# How does roc_curve() function calculates FPR, TPR values behind the scene. In my case, I got (53,) from (400,) dimensional input data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I was plotting roc curve. I have a neural network with one hidden layer based classifier. So my output is the result of activation function of final layer which I am calling A2; this will be probabilites input in `roc_curve()`. My A2 and predictions have following shapes and data:

```
print(A2.ravel().shape)
print(predictions.ravel().shape)
print(A2, predictions)
```

**Output:**

```
(400,)
(400,)
[[3.22246780e-04 7.64373268e-01 7.64385217e-01 7.64372464e-01
  1.63920340e-01 7.64372463e-01 2.75254103e-04 7.65185909e-01
  2.06186064e-01 2.12094433e-01 2.75251983e-04 7.64372463e-01
  2.11985152e-01 2.10202927e-01 2.75252955e-04 9.44088883e-02
  2.02522498e-01 2.07370306e-01 2.50282683e-03 2.75260253e-04
  2.11928461e-01 2.75251291e-04 2.75251291e-04 2.75251498e-04
  2.75251306e-04 1.35809613e-01 2.75464969e-04 1.74181943e-01
  2.75435676e-04 2.75251294e-04 2.96236579e-04 2.75268578e-04
  2.76053487e-04 2.78105904e-04 2.75293008e-04 2.75251307e-04
  2.87538148e-04 2.75270689e-04 2.39320951e-06 4.45134656e-02
  2.75251367e-04 2.75251506e-04 2.75251303e-04 2.31132556e-06
  3.69449012e-04 2.75251293e-04 5.59346558e-02 2.31132310e-06
  1.82980485e-01 6.20515482e-06 2.32293394e-02 1.58108674e-03
  2.75252597e-04 1.19360888e-02 2.27051743e-01 2.31161383e-06
  2.31132421e-06 2.31132310e-06 2.31573234e-06 2.31132310e-06
  5.15530179e-01 2.31132310e-06 2.31132311e-06 2.46803695e-06
  2.31132310e-06 2.31141693e-06 2.31132314e-06 2.31181353e-06
  1.08428788e-03 3.91750347e-01 2.15413251e-01 2.31136922e-06
  2.31132310e-06 2.31135038e-06 2.31132310e-06 4.18257225e-02
  2.31132310e-06 2.31692274e-06 2.31132315e-06 2.34152146e-06
  2.31132310e-06 2.31132310e-06 2.31134156e-06 2.32276423e-06
  2.31184444e-06 2.31189807e-06 2.31132310e-06 3.03902587e-06
  2.33123340e-06 6.74029292e-03 1.37374673e-04 7.11777353e-06
  2.31332212e-06 2.31134309e-06 2.85446765e-01 8.45686446e-04
  2.95393201e-06 6.30729453e-02 2.35681287e-06 1.67406531e-05
  1.39482094e-04 1.47208937e-05 2.64716376e-05 1.48764918e-05
  2.37288319e-06 1.76484186e-05 1.47209077e-05 4.24952409e-05
  2.47222738e-04 1.53198138e-05 5.10281474e-06 1.47209298e-05
  1.47208667e-05 2.64277585e-01 1.47208667e-05 1.55307243e-01
  1.47208865e-05 2.91081049e-03 1.47208667e-05 1.47208667e-05
  1.47208667e-05 1.47903704e-05 1.47238820e-05 3.11567098e-02
  4.14289114e-01 1.50836911e-05 2.78303520e-02 1.47208667e-05
  1.47251817e-05 1.47947695e-05 1.47208667e-05 1.47208667e-05
  1.47208940e-05 1.48783712e-05 2.05607558e-04 1.47208667e-05
  4.83812804e-05 1.47208667e-05 2.09377734e-01 1.49642652e-05
  1.47221481e-05 1.47568362e-05 2.77831915e-01 4.82959556e-01
  4.50969045e-01 3.82364226e-02 4.11377002e-02 2.16308926e-01
  8.88141165e-02 2.12679453e-01 2.24050631e-02 1.47208667e-05
  2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677760e-01 2.33568941e-01
  2.28926909e-01 2.13773365e-01 2.12678951e-01 1.35565877e-03
  2.47656669e-01 1.08727082e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12678014e-01
  2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01
  2.11844159e-01 1.51525672e-03 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01
  7.65697761e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01
  2.12668331e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01
  2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01 6.01467058e-02
  2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677495e-01 2.12677744e-01
  2.12677743e-01 2.12677744e-01 7.72857608e-01 2.09249431e-01
  7.86146268e-01 7.64683696e-01 8.39288704e-01 2.12677744e-01
  8.05987357e-01 7.73524718e-01 7.64722596e-01 7.64646794e-01
  2.12677744e-01 8.54868081e-01 7.66923142e-01 8.54244158e-01
  2.11261708e-01 7.66992993e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12598362e-01
  7.66165847e-01 9.99643109e-01 7.65268010e-01 9.99685903e-01
  9.99685903e-01 7.65043689e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01
  7.64840536e-01 9.99685901e-01 9.99332786e-01 2.12677743e-01
  7.79121852e-01 9.99685785e-01 7.79074180e-01 7.65194741e-01
  8.98667738e-01 9.99684795e-01 9.58419683e-01 9.99685902e-01
  9.99685882e-01 9.99639779e-01 9.99639274e-01 9.99677983e-01
  9.99685736e-01 9.99685902e-01 9.92940564e-01 9.99685903e-01
  9.99685839e-01 8.30995491e-01 9.90611316e-01 9.99997341e-01
  9.99670704e-01 9.23825584e-01 9.99685666e-01 9.99996824e-01
  9.99685902e-01 9.40290068e-01 9.99685903e-01 9.99996965e-01
  9.99685364e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99685801e-01 9.99997362e-01
  9.99996900e-01 9.99685513e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99684995e-01
  9.99676405e-01 9.99997362e-01 6.89410113e-01 5.28997119e-01
  9.93019339e-01 6.62017810e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01
  9.99997358e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997346e-01
  9.99997362e-01 9.99997352e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01
  9.99997362e-01 9.99071790e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01
  3.46195433e-01 9.99995537e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01
  9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99996894e-01
  7.67197871e-01 9.99997179e-01 1.65047845e-01 9.99978488e-01
  2.93981729e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997361e-01 9.29067186e-01
  9.99997362e-01 9.48399940e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01
  6.78299886e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.63677152e-01
  9.99997362e-01 3.67733752e-01 9.99997222e-01 7.74993071e-01
  6.37972260e-01 9.99943783e-01 9.77268446e-01 9.99976242e-01
  7.00255679e-01 9.99983200e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99983138e-01
  9.99983197e-01 9.86360906e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99389801e-01
  9.98380059e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01
  9.99983199e-01 9.99983199e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99391768e-01
  9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99981131e-01 9.99983201e-01
  9.99983201e-01 9.76520592e-01 8.44076103e-01 9.99983201e-01
  9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01
  9.99899640e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99983193e-01 9.99964112e-01
  9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 7.58322592e-01
  9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99981971e-01 7.64372463e-01
  7.64372463e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.06823611e-01 9.99983201e-01
  7.64372463e-01 9.99983201e-01 2.01516877e-01 7.64372463e-01
  3.98768426e-01 7.64372463e-01 9.81611504e-01 7.64372463e-01
  7.64372463e-01 7.64370725e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01
  9.99979567e-01 1.90105310e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01
  4.09226724e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01
  7.64372463e-01 7.64387743e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01
  7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01
  7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01
  7.76876797e-01 7.64372463e-01 2.07693046e-01 7.64372463e-01
  7.64372463e-01 7.59770748e-01 7.64372463e-01 7.64372463e-01
  7.66343703e-01 2.05588421e-01 7.64372828e-01 2.06636497e-01
  1.97645490e-01 2.09816835e-01 7.64372464e-01 1.77842165e-01]] [[0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
  0 0 1 0]]
```

Now when I input these values in `roc_curve()`, I get fpr, tpr, threshold of following shapes and size:

```
fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(Y.ravel(), A2.ravel())
print(fpr.shape, tpr.shape, threshold.shape)
print(fpr, tpr, threshold)
```

**Output:**

```
(53,) (53,) (53,)
[0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.005 0.005 0.015 0.015
 0.025 0.025 0.03  0.03  0.035 0.035 0.05  0.05  0.06  0.06  0.065 0.065
 0.075 0.075 0.095 0.095 0.1   0.1   0.19  0.27  0.285 0.285 0.3   0.3
 0.32  0.32  0.325 0.325 0.335 0.335 0.34  0.34  0.345 0.345 0.35  0.35
 0.355 0.355 0.36  0.36  1.   ] [0.    0.015 0.045 0.19  0.23  0.235 0.245 0.615 0.615 0.62  0.62  0.64
 0.64  0.665 0.665 0.675 0.675 0.685 0.685 0.69  0.69  0.7   0.7   0.715
 0.825 0.895 0.895 0.905 0.905 0.92  0.92  0.935 0.935 0.945 0.945 0.95
 0.95  0.955 0.955 0.96  0.96  0.965 0.965 0.97  0.97  0.975 0.975 0.99
 0.99  0.995 0.995 1.    1.   ] [1.99999736e+00 9.99997362e-01 9.99997362e-01 9.99995537e-01
 9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 9.99983201e-01 8.44076103e-01
 8.39288704e-01 8.30995491e-01 7.86146268e-01 7.74993071e-01
 7.72857608e-01 7.66165847e-01 7.65697761e-01 7.65194741e-01
 7.65185909e-01 7.64840536e-01 7.64646794e-01 7.64387743e-01
 7.64373268e-01 7.64372464e-01 7.64372464e-01 7.64372463e-01
 7.64372463e-01 5.28997119e-01 4.14289114e-01 3.98768426e-01
 3.91750347e-01 2.93981729e-01 2.12677744e-01 2.12677744e-01
 2.12677744e-01 2.12677743e-01 2.12668331e-01 2.12598362e-01
 2.11844159e-01 2.11261708e-01 2.10202927e-01 2.09816835e-01
 2.09249431e-01 2.07693046e-01 2.07370306e-01 2.06636497e-01
 2.06186064e-01 2.05588421e-01 2.02522498e-01 1.90105310e-01
 1.82980485e-01 1.77842165e-01 1.74181943e-01 1.65047845e-01
 2.31132310e-06]
```

And hence my roc curve looks like this:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic(ROC Curve)')
```

**Output:**
[image]

Why I am getting `(53,)` shapes of FPR, TPR, Threshold? My case is just simple two class classification. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of thresholds is calculated as follows:

- **Step 1**: keep unique score values, plus 1.

[Source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2e/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L716):

```
# y_score typically has many tied values. Here we extract
# the indices associated with the distinct values. We also
# concatenate a value for the end of the curve.
distinct_value_indices = np.where(np.diff(y_score))[0]
threshold_idxs = np.r_[distinct_value_indices, y_true.size - 1]
```

- **Step 2** (if `if drop_intermediate and len(fps) > 2`): drop thresholds corresponding to points in between and collinear with other points.

[Source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2e/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L916):

```
# Attempt to drop thresholds corresponding to points in between and
# collinear with other points. These are always suboptimal and do not
# appear on a plotted ROC curve (and thus do not affect the AUC).
# Here np.diff(_, 2) is used as a "second derivative" to tell if there
# is a corner at the point. Both fps and tps must be tested to handle
# thresholds with multiple data points (which are combined in
# _binary_clf_curve). This keeps all cases where the point should be kept,
# but does not drop more complicated cases like fps = [1, 3, 7],
# tps = [1, 2, 4]; there is no harm in keeping too many thresholds.
if drop_intermediate and len(fps) > 2:
    optimal_idxs = np.where(np.r_[True,
                                  np.logical_or(np.diff(fps, 2),
                                                np.diff(tps, 2)),
                                  True])[0]
    fps = fps[optimal_idxs]
    tps = tps[optimal_idxs]
    thresholds = thresholds[optimal_idxs]
```

The FPR and TPR are then calculated for each threshold value.